# Узнать тип параметра функции

Tags: c++

У меня есть шаблонный параметр, принимающий вызываемый тип. Как узнать тип i-ого параметра этого функционального объекта/функции?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <type_traits>
#include <functional>


template<typename Foo>
void print_second_parameter_type() {
    std::cout << typeid(...).name() << '\n';
}


int main() {
    // должно печатать тип второго параметра => typeid(int).name()
    print_second_parameter_type<std::plus<int>>();
}
```

В документации сказано, что раньше для этого можно было использовать `::second_argument_type` конкретно у `std::plus<>`, но с `C++17` это устарело.

Comment: т.к. operator() может быть перегружен, то для объектов это теряет смысл.

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте так:

```
template<typename T>
struct extract_value_type { using type = T; };

template<template<typename> class X, typename T>
struct extract_value_type <X<T>> { using type = T; };

template <typename T>
void print_second_parameter_type() {
    std::cout << typeid(typename extract_value_type<T>::type).name() << '\n';
}
```

Если может встречаться шаблонный шаблонный параметр, то можно сделать рекурсивый обход параметров:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
struct extract_value_type { using type = T; };

template<template<typename> class X, typename... Arg>
struct extract_value_type <X<Arg...>> { using type = typename extract_value_type<Arg...>::type; };

template <typename T>
struct X {};

template <typename T>
void print_second_parameter_type() {
    std::cout << typeid(typename extract_value_type<T>::type).name() << '\n';
}

int main() {
    print_second_parameter_type<std::plus<int>>();
    print_second_parameter_type<X<std::plus<int>>>();
    return 0;
}
```

Но это будет работать, если передаваемый тип имеет только один парметр. Например для `print_second_parameter_type<std::vector<std::plus<int>>>();` вывод будет `class std::vector<struct std::plus<int>,class std::allocator<struct std::plus<int> > >` вместо `int`